# What's the best way to model Friendship using Java Hibernate and JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Let's say I have a Person entity.

And a Person can have a 'Friendship' relationship with one or more other Persons.

I would model that with, say, an entry in a table

```
| Person Id 1 | Person Id 2 |
```

But, semantically, if Person 1 is friends with Person 2

```
| Person Id 1 | Person Id 2 |
```

it is the same as saying Person 2 is friends with Person 1

```
| Person Id 2 | Person Id 1 |
```

Of course, there are lots of ways in Java, and in the query, such as `((person1=x AND person2=y) OR (person1=y AND person2=x))` that I would make sure that this equivalence is honoured. But what's a more efficient way to model this *in the database* itself, and in subsequent Repository, JPQL Queries etc.

**To summarise**; I want to be able to check whether Person 1 is friends with Person 2, without having two checks - (is Person 1 friends with Person 2) *or* (is Person 2 friends with Person 1). Idiomatically, I just want to say (are Person 1 and Person 2 friends).

I want to implicitly model the equivalence that is A is friends with B then B is automatically friends with A.

Answer (score 1):

- The following person entity class

```
    @Entity
    public class Person {

    //Id and properties

      @ManyToMany
      @JoinTable(name="friendship", 
                joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="person_id")}, 
                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friend_id")})
       private Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<Person>();

       // Getter and Setter methods
     }
```

- It will generate a `person` table and a `friendship` table. `person` table will only contain information related to `Person` and `friendship` table will only have two columns `person_id` and `friend_id` to keep the relationship.

Comment: I am thinking exactly the same, but not sure about it will work or not for self @ManyToMany relation (didn't get enough time to test it accually)

Comment: It should work  but @ManyToMany cannot be `EAGER`, otherwise it will keep fetching forever

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn’t resolve my main problem  To check whether Person 1 is friends with Person 2, I would still have to check if ((Person 1 is friends with Person 2) or (is Person 2 friends with Person 1). It doesn’t implicitly model the equivalence that is A is friends with B then B is automatically friends with A